# Regular Expression To find <jdoc:include type="component" />

Tags: regex

I need to replace `<jdoc:include type="component" />` in my docs with another string in PHP.  So whitespace is important to me because the expression may be like all of these or more:

```
<jdoc:include type="component"           />
<jdoc:include                    type="component" />
<jdoc:include type="component" xxxxx />
```

or more ...

Comment: In what language, on what platform?

Comment: Which part exactly do you want to replace in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<jdoc:include\s+type="component"\s+\/>`

Answer (score 0):

While playing with **sed** on bash, I did the following: created a file named **test.php** with all your strings inside it:

```
<jdoc:include type="component"           />
<jdoc:include                    type="component" />
<jdoc:include type="component" xxxxx />
```

And then elaborated a single regex that matches all cases and replace them for `<jdoc:include type="stackoverflow" />`.

Enjoy:

```
sed -r 's/<jdoc:include\s+type=\"component\"\s+\w*\s*\/>/<jdoc:include type=\"stackoverflow\" \/>/' test.php
```

If you are wandering:

`\s+` means match 1 or more whitespaces

`\w*` means match any character in the range 0 - 9, A - Z and a - z

[This page](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm) is a great resource for regex.

Comment: @ShirazITCo It's important for all of us that you review the answers and ACCEPT the one that solved your question.